# Sequential synchronous circuit exercise

Tags: synchronous, sequential-logic

I need some help in understanding an exercise.

Here I have a State Diagram (Moore Machine), and the exercise asks me to write the table of transitions between states and machine outputs.
[image]
I can understand almost everything, but something is confusing me, the outputs expression, I have no idea how to determine what is the output value by those expressions.
Normally in this type exercises the output is represented by 0 or 1 like this [image]

But as you can see in the exercise it is represented by expressions, while I don't realize it I can't determine the next state in the transition table.

Can someone explain to me how can I do it? Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The top diagram is for a machine with two inputs, A and B. The transition is taken when the given Boolean expression evaluates to true. This machine has one output, F, and the value of the output is shown in each state "bubble".

The bottom diagram is for a machine with just one input, so the transitions are marked with the value of the input that will cause the transition to be taken.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, so but for example how can I know the value of S2(A.B'), it means that A=1 and (B')=0?

Comment: Yes, if a transition is labeled with \$A\cdot \overline{B}\$ then that transition will occur if and only if \$A = 1\$ AND \$B=0\$.

Comment: Ok, but when A=1 AND B=0 that means that my OUTPUT  value is 0? A⋅B' = 0?